# Near-end scan different frequency magnetic field propagations in ideal DC source

Tags: near-field, pcb-simulation

I installed a simple PCB on Ansys siwave. I defined the power lines. And I defined an ideal voltage source that gives only 18 V on the pins. I set the near fields analysis as you can see.

interestingly, in near field scanning, I see magnetic fields occurring at 200 and 900 MHz. How is this possible in a DC power supply? Is the simulation giving an erroneous result or is there something I missed?(note that I only added a dc voltage source, no current source or oscillating signal lines)I am confused whether the copper on the pcb as a transient induces a signal at a certain frequency or does it induce it continuously.
[image]

[image]

[here some example](https://resources.altium.com/p/identifying-near-field-emi-pcbs-power-distribution-network)

[image]